# Migration conversion of float data to decimal data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, floating-point

I am migrating data from one table to a new table. The old table uses FLOAT, and in the new table I am using DECIMAL as the field attribute.

I am using the following statement which worked fine:
CAST(OLD_COLUMN_NAME as DECIMAL(9,2) AS 'NEW_COLUMN_NAME'

that works like a charm until I hit the bump in the road. The old data is defined as float,null, the new field is defined as decimal(5,5). I understand that decimal(5,5) will requires all data behind the decimal for 5 positions. Just wondering if they is any way to handle this problem of moving data from a float data field to a decimal data field.

The input data from the old field is varied and looks like this: 5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 2, and so forth.

The error I am receiving is:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 6, Line 8  Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric.The statement has been terminated.

The code is against a SQL SERVER 2005 database using SQL SERVER 2008. Not sure this matters, but thought I would include this information.

Could someone shed some light on how to address this data conversion issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`Decimal(5, 5)` only has a range - 0.99999 to + 0.99999

but you say you are trying to put `5` and `2` into it. Do you need `Decimal(10, 5)`?

If not you have indeed been left a bit of a conundrum.

I mention the following as a point of interest rather than a serious suggestion, though, who knows, it may be useful!

If the column is nullable one way to fullfill your bosses requirements would be

```
create table #t (j int,i Decimal(5, 5)  null)

set ansi_warnings off
set arithabort off

insert into #t values(1,0.2345678)
insert into #t values(2,10)
insert into #t values(3,0.455464)

select * from #t
```

Output

```
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
j           i
----------- ------------------------------
1           0.23457
2           NULL
3           0.45546
```

Comment: I understand but I cannot change the output format, my boss wants to see it as Decimal(5,5). I am at a loss of how to do this.

Comment: I was going to suggest this but was too lazy to look up the actual numbers.

Comment: Well the column simply won't take `5` or `2` are you asking how to exclude those or do you just want to store the decimal part for these numbers (i.e. 0)

Comment: @Martin - I can't imagine they want to lose the data. I get the feeling the boss simply does not understand how the decimal type works.

Comment: I agree Martin it seems impossible. The suggestion ChasPandion made of
Cast(Round(field, 5) As Decimal(5, 5)) was so close but the column name is not recognized..:)  Seems like I have been given a real conundrum.

Comment: @Chaos - I agree. To be honest I don't blame the boss. I must have looked the scale,precision thing up a number of times as well.

Comment: @Martin - I really don't blame him. Just a bit grumpy after work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing something like this.

```
Cast(Round(field, 5) As Decimal(5, 5))
```

Comment: tried this and got the errorMsg 8115, Level 16, State 6, Line 17
Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric.

Comment: check that I have retried this. 
Here is the code:

SELECT top 700
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), cLehmanNo) as 'LOAN_NUMBER'
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),cInvestorID) as 'INVESTOR_ID'
,CAST(ROUND(fLateChargeFact,5) as Decimal (5,5))
INTO #LTS_MAP2
FROM Loanmaster
Now I get this error: Msg 1038, Level 15, State 5, Line 8
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Answer (score 1):

Does your boss understand that decimal(5,5) won't allow anything to the left of the decimal point?

Ask your boss what he/she wants in plain english.  If your boss is really asking you to store numbers greater than .99999, but insisting specifically on "decimal(5,5)", then clearly they don't understand what they're asking for.  The first "5" in decimal(5,5) refers to the total number of digits in the number (before and after combined)